# What's the difference between a value of a dual and a solution of a dual?

Tags: linear-programming, numerical-optimization

In this video on total dual integrality: https://youtu.be/l8YdPRxqlXo?list=PLXsmhnDvpjORcTRFMVF3aUgyYlHsxfhNL&t=798

> If the dual has an integral solution, not just an integral value ...

The professor emphasizes that the dual must have an integral **solution** and not an integral **value**, saying that it's because this is a specialization and hence is weaker.

What exactly does he mean by making this differentiation between **solution** and **value**?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

By integral *value*, he means $y^T b\in\mathbb{Z}$.  By integral *solution*, he means $y\in\mathbb{Z}^m$.